# How to use auto_increment comand after the table is already created in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have a table named `employee` which has three columns `empid` (which is `int`), `empname` (`varchar`) and `salary`(`int`). I have already made the table and inserted some data as well. Now I want to make `empid` autoincrement.

I used the command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee ADD AUTO_INCREMENT(empid);
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(empid)' at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to alter the table, to modify the column itself, and add the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to that column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee 
MODIFY empid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

If it isn't already the primary key, you should add that as well

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee 
MODIFY empid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```